# Bit ordering in a byte when using bitfields

Tags: c

C a reference manual states that "The precise manner in which components( and especially bit fields) are packed into a structure is implementation dependent but is predictable for each implementation".

I read that some compilers pack bit fields  left to right ( MSB to LSB) in Big endian machines whereas right to left(LSB to MSB) in Little endian machines.

is there a  reason/advantage about representing bitfields in two diffrent ways depends on the endianness?

Comment: In answer to your questions, the short answer is **No**. Because, whether bits are packed left->right or right->left is by hardware convention. There isn't a one way is better/worse, that is just how differing hardware implementations handle numbers/structures to account/accommodate the endianness of the machine. The user only cares that he knows the order the bits are stored so that he gets back what he intends to get back. The packing/ordering isn't something the user sees or cares about - 99.9% of the time.

Answer (score 5):

I've not implemented this, but I can imagine that it has to do with working with bit fields in registers, and reading/writing entire words to/from the structure when possible. If you implement it that way, instead of doing byte-level accesses, you will of course "feel" the endianness as the word is byte-swapped in memory.

So if you have

```
 struct color {
  uint32_t red : 8;
  uint32_t green : 8;
  uint32_t blue : 8;
  uint32_t alpha : 8;
 };
```

When you do

```
struct color orange = { .red = 255, .green = 127, .blue = 0, .alpha = 0 };
```

It might be implemented (since the fields are conveniently sized) as

```
struct color orange;
uint32_t *tmp = *(uint32_t *) &orange;
*tmp = 0xff7f0000;  /* The field values, mapping red to the MSBs. */
```

Now, since the above does one single `uint32_t`-sized memory write, the value will be byte-swapped on a little-endian machine but not on a big-endian one, i.e. when viewed byte by byte, the representations are different.

Answer (score 1):

Layout of bit fields inside a structure is implementation defined. It is not a good idea to use them if you need portable code.